# ASP.NET multilingual through cookie/URL - Google sees one version

Tags: seo, css, asp.net, language, cookie

Our website is multilingual and works through cookies/URL

- `www.amlik.com/ar/`
- `www.amlik.com/en/`

The problem we are facing is Google sees only the arabic (default version of our site) even when visiting `en` page.

Has anyone succeeded in using such an infrastructure with ASP.NET before?

It could be a coding error on our behalf, just want to make sure.